# my store procedure with cursors does not run

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my query . I am following all the steps to create a procedure with cursors, but does not work

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_prueba1` (
codigo1 int,
estado1 int,
llave_maestra1 char(10),
fecha_actual1 date,
rango_inicial1 varchar(20),
rango_final1 varchar(20))
BEGIN
     DECLARE est1 int;
     DECLARE conteo1 int;
     /*Abro cursor*/
     DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR  SELECT Oel_Estado FROM        Operaciones_Especiales_Llave  WHERE Em_Codigo=codigo1; 
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
     OPEN cur1;
    /*INICIO LOOP*/
     read_loop: LOOP
       FETCH cur1 INTO  est1;
                     IF done THEN

                        LEAVE read_loop;

                     ELSE

                        SELECT conteo1,finicio1,ffin1,cod1,est1; 

                    END IF; 
      END LOOP;
     /*FIN LOOP*/
      CLOSE cur1;
    /*CIERRO CURSOR*/     
END
```

[image]

What is my mistake ? please

Comment: Try commenting out some of the lines to work out what line the syntax error is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing your `Delimiters`.

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server. To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command.

```
Delimiter //

  CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_prueba1` (
codigo1 int,
estado1 int,
llave_maestra1 char(10),
fecha_actual1 date,
rango_inicial1 varchar(20),
rango_final1 varchar(20))
BEGIN
     DECLARE est1 int;
     DECLARE conteo1 int;
     /*Abro cursor*/
     DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR  SELECT Oel_Estado FROM        Operaciones_Especiales_Llave  WHERE Em_Codigo=codigo1; 
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
     OPEN cur1;
    /*INICIO LOOP*/
     read_loop: LOOP
       FETCH cur1 INTO  est1;
                     IF done THEN

                        LEAVE read_loop;

                     ELSE

                        SELECT conteo1,finicio1,ffin1,cod1,est1; 

                    END IF; 
      END LOOP;
     /*FIN LOOP*/
      CLOSE cur1;
    /*CIERRO CURSOR*/     
END

Delimiter;
```

In the future please refer to [Dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html).